# How to UNINSTALL a Bluetooth interface Linux?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, uninstall

I want to uninstall a Bluetooth interface on Kali Linux (just basic Debian, Ubuntu fixes may work too). This is because I have two adapters and I only want to use one. Just "downing" the device isn't enough since it cause naming issues for the other device (annoying suffix).

How would I remove and interface so that it doesn't show up in `hciconfig`?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I can try to improve my question if needed, but let me know :)